# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property once of [object Object] which has only a getter

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, npm-install, npm-scripts

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property once of [object Object] which has only a getter at HTMLDivElement.addEventListener (polyfills.js:1:146664)

Facing this above issue while upgrading angular version.

Please check image

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Version 2.7 of @webcomponents/webcomponentsjs seems to have introduced a bug which causes this error. I found it through the interaction of zone.js and webcomponents, also in an Angular project.
The bug description is here: https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/issues/531

It seems to not have been fixed as of version 2.8, so the proposed workaround seems to be to downgrade to version 2.6.